# Excel VBA efficient get file names function

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, filesystemobject

I need to get a collection of file names from a folder on a remote server using VBA in excel 2010. I have a function that works and in the majority of cases it would do the job, however the remote server frequently has terrible, **terrible** network performance issues.  This means that looping through say 300 files to put their names into a collection can take 10 minutes, the number of files in the folder is likely to grow to thousands so this is not workable, I need a way to get all of the file names in a single network request and not looping.  I believe its connecting to the remote server that is taking the time so a single request should be able to get all of the files in one pass fairly quickly.

This is the function I currently have in place:

```
Private Function GetFileNames(sPath As String) As Collection
'takes a path and returns a collection of the file names in the folder

Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim colList     As New Collection

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(folderpath:=sPath)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    colList.Add oFile.Name
Next oFile

Set GetFileNames = colList

Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: + 1 Good question :) You almost had me thinking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution that works for my situation and perhaps others will find it useful too. This soution uses the windows API and gets me the filenames in 1 second or less where as the FSO method was taking several minutes.  It still involves a loop so i'm not certain why it is so much faster but it is.

This takes a path like "c:\windows\" and returns a collection of all the files (and directories) in that folder.  The exact parameters I have used require windows 7 or newer, see the comments in the declarations.

```
'for windows API call to FindFirstFileEx
Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260

Private Type FILETIME
    dwLowDateTime   As Long
    dwHighDateTime  As Long
End Type

Private Type WIN32_FIND_DATA
    dwFileAttributes    As Long
    ftCreationTime      As FILETIME
    ftLastAccessTime    As FILETIME
    ftLastWriteTime     As FILETIME
    nFileSizeHigh       As Long
    nFileSizeLow        As Long
    dwReserved0         As Long
    dwReserved1         As Long
    cFileName           As String * MAX_PATH
    cAlternate          As String * 14
End Type

Private Const FIND_FIRST_EX_CASE_SENSITIVE  As Long = 1
'MSDN: "This value is not supported until Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7."
Private Const FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH     As Long = 2

Private Enum FINDEX_SEARCH_OPS
    FindExSearchNameMatch
    FindExSearchLimitToDirectories
    FindExSearchLimitToDevices
End Enum

Private Enum FINDEX_INFO_LEVELS
    FindExInfoStandard
    FindExInfoBasic 'MSDN: "This value is not supported until Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7."
    FindExInfoMaxInfoLevel
End Enum

Private Declare Function FindFirstFileEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "FindFirstFileExA" ( _
ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal fInfoLevelId As Long, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, _
    ByVal fSearchOp As Long, ByVal lpSearchFilter As Long, ByVal dwAdditionalFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindNextFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "FindNextFileA" ( _
    ByVal hFindFile As Long, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
Private Declare Function FindClose Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFindFile As Long) As Long


Private Function GetFiles(ByVal sPath As String) As Collection

    Dim fileInfo    As WIN32_FIND_DATA  'buffer for file info
    Dim hFile       As Long             'file handle
    Dim colFiles    As New Collection

    sPath = sPath & "*.*"

    hFile = FindFirstFileEx(sPath & vbNullChar, FindExInfoBasic, fileInfo, FindExSearchNameMatch, 0&, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH)

    If hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
        Do While FindNextFile(hFile, fileInfo)
            colFiles.Add Left(fileInfo.cFileName, InStr(fileInfo.cFileName, vbNullChar) - 1)
        Loop

        FindClose hFile
    End If

    Set GetFiles = colFiles

End Function
```

Answer (score 9):

This one is lightning fast:

```
  Sub filesTest()
    Dim x() As String
    x = Function_FileList("YOUR_PATH_AND_FOLDER_NAME")
    Debug.Print Join(x, vbCrLf)
  End Sub
```

Which calls this function:

```
 Function Function_FileList(FolderLocation As String)
    Function_FileList = Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & FolderLocation & """ /b /a-d").stdout.readall, vbCrLf), ".")
 End Function
```

Comment: + 1 Simply beautiful!

Comment: It's no faster if you have a slow network connection or lots of files. `dir` iterates internally, and running it through `exec` means it runs on your local machine and suffers the same network latency.

Comment: @KenWhite What if the above code is put in a batch file and the file is then copied to the remote folder and then run from there?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Unless you use `rexec` or something similar, it will still run on the local machine and retrieve the list over the network. The question was not about running a process on a remote machine and then transferring a file, however; it was about retrieving a directory list without iterating, and that simply isn't possible. (Raymond Chen wrote a series of articles about this issue as related to Explorer retrieving file lists over slow network connections, but I don't have a link to them handy.)

Comment: @KenWhite: Hmm, What if then not retrieving the list over network but outputting the list in the remote folder to a text file and then retrieving that textfile?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: See my comment to your answer. :-)

Comment: @tbur: That's an interesting approach, I'd love to test it to compare the performance, however I cannot invoke CMD or any executable that isn't white-listed for my user account.  I tried running the function but got a run-time error "This program is blocked by group policy". Any solution would have to be limited to the office object model, VBA, or a COM library that is already present.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that there would be an API which could get me the file names in a directory without looping but couldn't find it. All the code that I know of involves looping either using `fso` or `dir`.

So is it possible to get the file names without looping. I guess yes... Here is one way I can think of...

When you type the below command in DOS Prompt, the entire file structure is sent to a text file

```
Dir C:\Temp\*.* > C:\Temp\MyFile.Txt
```

Doing the above from VBA

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "C:\Temp\"

    '~~> DIR C:\Temp\*.* > C:\Temp\MyFile.txt
    retval = Shell("cmd.exe /c Dir " & sPath & "*.* > " & sPath & "MyFile.Txt")
End Sub
```

For example (This is what is stored in MyFile.Txt)

```
Volume in drive C is XXXXXXX
Volume Serial Number is XXXXXXXXX

Directory of C:\Temp

10/08/2014  11:28 PM    <DIR>          .
10/08/2014  11:28 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/08/2014  11:27 PM               832 aaa.txt
10/08/2014  11:28 PM                 0 bbb.txt
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_2.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_2_2.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_3.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_3_2.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_4.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_4_2.bmp
10/08/2014  11:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image_5.bmp
            10 File(s)            832 bytes
             2 Dir(s)  424,786,952,192 bytes free
```

So now all you need to do is copy the text file from the remote folder to your folder and simply parse it to get the file names.

Comment: This still runs the `dir` command from the local machine and requests the file listing across the network. Running it via `cmd.exe` still executes it locally. You'd have to copy a batch file or script across the network, execute it remotely using `rexec` or something similar, and then transfer the resulting file across the network once that remote process finished (meaning you'd have to wait and poll for it to complete).

Comment: True but I guess this is the only option OP has for the time being?

Comment: It's not going to be an improvement. :-) The overhead of launching the file via `rexec`, polling, and then transferring the text file (and then parsing the text file to get the file list) is going to have a performance impact.

Comment: I just had a thought... what if we give the full path of the cmd (of that machine) so that it doesn't run the cmd from the local machine?

Comment: Won't work. cmd would still run on the local machine. In order to run it on the remote machine, you have to actually *execute it* on the remote machine (in that machine's own operating system), not the local one. Running it from the local machine with a remote path would simply result in the entire application (cmd.exe) being retrieved in order to execute on the local OS.

Comment: ah I see... I was not aware of that.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thanks for this, however I cannot use CMD, see my comment to the answer above.