# Unable to open file using fso

Tags: excel, filesystemobject, fso, vba

I'm trying to open a file using FileSystemObject, but when I'm trying to run it, the system does nothing. Doesn't show me Debug, No runtime error, doesn't compile. It just remains as it is.
I have also checked the "MS Scripting Runtime" in References.
Below is the code I've used for this:

```
Sub fsoobject()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, f As Folder, sf As Folder, myFile As File
Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\jpmehta\Desktop")

For Each sf In f.SubFolders
    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
        For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
            If myFile.Name Like "Done" Then
                MsgBox myFile.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        MsgBox "Else"
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `myFolder` with `sf`

Comment: Still not happening :(

Comment: The only thing `Like "Done"` is "Done" - perhaps you need wildcards.

Comment: As SJR said, [wildcard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx) such as `Like "*Done*"`

Comment: @JayyM shouldn't `For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders` be `For Each mySubFolder In sf.SubFolders` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, I tried replacing that too, but it's not happening.

Comment: @SJR here, "Done" is my .jpg file name... is there something in that name that hinders the code? shall I change the file name?

Comment: Are you looking for a file called "Done" or something containing "Done" such as "Undone" or "Not done yet"? As @danieltakeshi says `"Like "*Done*"` will match something containing "Done". If `myFile.Name` includes the file extension (I can't remember whether it will but easy to check) then you will need a wildcard, at least at the end.

Comment: Try if instr(1, myFile.Name , "Done") > 0 then MsgBox myFile.Name.  Remember that case is important.  Perhaps try instr(1, ucase(myFile.Name) , "DONE")  > 0 then MsgBox myFile.Name.

Comment: I heard a function called Shell which is used to open a file.. If that is so, what will be the line for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub fsoobject()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
dim f As Folder
dim  sf As Folder
dim mySubFolder as folder 
dim  myFile As File
 Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\jpmehta\Desktop")
 dim found as boolean 'flag if found 
 For Each sf In f.SubFolders
     For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
         For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
             If myFile.Name Like "Done*.*" Then
                  MsgBox mysubfolder.path & "\" & myFile.Name
                  found = true 'we found it
                  Exit For 'so stop
              End If
        Next myFile
        if found then exit for  'cascade exit
    Next MySubFolder
    if found then exit for 'and again
 next sf

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub fsoobject()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, f As Folder, sf As Folder, myFile As File
Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\jpmehta\Desktop")

'For Each sf In f.SubFolders
'    For Each mySubFolder In sf.SubFolders
'        For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
'            If myFile.Name Like "Done" Then
'                MsgBox myFile.Name
'                Exit For
'            End If
'        Next
'
'        MsgBox "Else"
'    Next
'Next

    Dim File
    For Each File In f.Files
        If File.Name = "Done.PNG" Then
            Call Shell("Explorer.exe """ & File.Path & """", vbNormalFocus)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Well, I searched a bit, and found this keyword "Shell" to open a file. On applying this code, now it executes successfully...

Comment: The use of [shell is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26262962/7690982) than fso.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Clear and simple:

```
Sub fsoobject()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, f As Folder, sf As Folder, ssf As Folder, 
myFile As File
Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\tomek\Desktop")

For Each sf In f.SubFolders
    Set ssf = sf

    For Each myFile In ssf.Files
        If myFile.Name Like "Done" Then
            Debug.Print myFile.Name
            Exit For
        End If

    Debug.Print "Else:" & myFile.Name

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

1. set subsubfolder (Set ssf = sf)
2. I recommend to use Debug.Print to check loops in VBE