# Get the Worksheet Name of all the .xlsx Workbooks inside a directory

Tags: vba, excel

I have a textbox where I am getting an Input Directory and calculating the number of .xlsx reports and the total number of worksheets in those report.

I would like to get the report name and sheetname of each of those report.

What could be the quickest way to get that.

As there are cases where it could be 100 workbooks and total of 1000 worksheets inside them.

Here goes my code which Just gets the number of reports and worksheets in those reports.

```
Private Sub FL_TextBox_Change()


Dim FolderPath As String
Dim path As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim Wk As Workbook

Dim Ws As Workbook
Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook

FolderPath = NewTask.FL_TextBox.Value

MsgBox ("Click Ok & Wait for the Total Number of Reports and Worksheets" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "to be calculated.")

If FolderPath = "" Then

     NewTask.Num_Rpt_TextBox.Value = ""

     Ws.Sheets("Config").Range("I1").Value = ""

Else

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xlsx"
    Filename = Dir(path)
    File = (FolderPath & "\" & Filename)
    wkcount = 0
    Shcount = 0
    shtcount = 0
    RptSheets = ""
    Do While Filename <> ""
        wkcount = wkcount + 1
        File = FolderPath & "\" & Filename
        Set Wk = Workbooks.Open(File, ReadOnly:=True)
        Shcount = Wk.Sheets.count
        If RptSheets <> "" Then
           RptSheets = RptSheets & "," & Shcount
        Else
           RptSheets = Shcount
        End If
        Wk.Close
        shtcount = shtcount + Shcount
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

Ws.Sheets("Config").Range("I1").Value = RptSheets
XlsxFilesPresent = wkcount & " / " & shtcount
NewTask.Num_Rpt_TextBox.Value = XlsxFilesPresent
End If

End Sub
```

So, in short - I want to get the number of .xlsx reports and those report names and number of worksheets inside those report and the worksheet names in a structured way.

Something like

```
Number of workbooks = 3

Number of Worksheets = 100

ReportNames = TestFile1, TestFile2, TestFile3.
```

`SheetNames = TestFile1:TestSheet1, TestFile1:TestSheet2, TestFile1:TestSheet3, TestFile1:TestSheet4` etc.,

Kindly share your thoughts in getting this process running faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA efficient get file names function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262962/excel-vba-efficient-get-file-names-function)

Comment: @Ralph I would need the sheet names as well. I did saw the question and I think - My Requirements were similar to that but not exactly the same.

Comment: You can use the ADO OpenSchema method to get the worksheet names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have everything you need, you just need to add some lines to make an object that contains all of the data you need and then you can use that object to extract anything you want and I cannot think of anything better than a dictionary object.

All of the information of the sheets are stored in a collection object called `worksheets` so you can simply store that object and iterate through it to access worksheet names and possibly any other information you want. So first create a collection object and a dictionary object like this:

```
Dim coll As Object
Dim dict As Object

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
```

Inside your `do while` loop use workbook names as keys and the worksheets object of that workbook as the item. Note that the keys should be unique and I assume that you will run this in one directory so file names must be unique forced by your OS.

To add keys and items inside the loop after you opened the workbook use this:

```
set coll=wk.Worksheets
dict.add Wk,coll
```

once the execution gets out of the loop you have a dictionary of all workbooks and their worksheets object. Now you can loop through the dictionary and form the data however you want. for example, let's say you want to print the workbook name and then the worksheets:

```
dim i as integer
dim key as variant
Dim sht As Worksheet

for each key in dict.keys
    set coll=dict(key) 'sets the item of the dict=worksheets
    For i = 1 To coll.Count 'loop through worksheets object and print their names
        Set sht = coll(i)
        Debug.Print key & ":" & sht.Name
    Next
next key
```